# How to pass an array of primitive types as object array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, primitive-types

I wanted the following function to be generic for all data types. However, this does not work with the primitive data types. Why is that?
Can anyone give a solution to this? I would greatly appreciate it.

```
private int getIndexOfElement(Object x, Object[] xArray){
        for(int i=0; i<xArray.length;i++){
            if(xArray[i]==x){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return  -1;
    }
```

Comment: Primitives are not objects. Simple. This cannot be done.

Comment: Something like this can be done with reflection using [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/array.html), but almost certainly not recommended. Reflection is clunky and error-prone so you'd think carefully about whether it's actually a good decision to use it. Useful to know about, though.

Comment: In Java 8 you can use this: `Arrays.stream( data ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new )` to convert a primitives array to an objects array.

Comment: @Titus are you suggesting _copying_ the whole array to a **new** array just to find the index? That seems somewhat...unwise.

Answer (score 3):

Your method `getIndexOfElement(int,Object[])` accepts any array of type, that extends `Object`. Since `int` is primitive type - not a class type, you can not pass `int[]` to the method. However, you can use `Integer` class:

```
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    Integer i = 5;
    int index = getIndexOfElement(i, ints);
```